# Perturbation theory of $\lambda q^4$ perturbed harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

For a perturbed Hamiltonian

$$
H = H^{(0)} + H'
$$

the perturbation theory approach

$$
\Psi = \Psi^{(0)} + \lambda \Psi^{(1)} + ... \\
E = E^{(0)} + \lambda E^{(1)} + ...
$$

leads to the equations

$$
\begin{align}
H^{(0)}\Psi^{(0)}& =E^{(0)}\Psi^{(0)} \tag 1 \\
(H^{(0)}-E^{(0)})\Psi^{(1)} & = (E^{(1)}-H')\Psi^{(0)} \tag 2
\end{align}
$$

For a perturbed harmonic oscillator

$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac 12 m\omega^2 q^2 + \lambda q^4
$$

we get

$$
\begin{align}
H^{(0)} & = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac 12 m\omega^2 q^2 \\
E_n^{(0)} & = \hbar\omega(n+\frac 12) \\
\Psi^{(0)} & = |n\rangle
\end{align}
$$

If we are only interested in the energy shift $\Delta E_n = E_n^{(1)}$ for the first order of $\lambda$, we get from $(2)$:

$$
\tag{3}(H^{(0)}-E_n^{(0)})\Psi^{(1)} = (\Delta E_n-q^4)|n\rangle
$$

On the bottom of page 4 of [this script](http://yclept.ucdavis.edu/course/242/2Q_Fradkin.pdf), exactly the same is done, but somehow they get

$$
\tag{4}\Delta E_n = \lambda\langle n|q^4|n\rangle + O(\lambda^2)
$$

How can I get $(4)$ from $(3)$? Or, if the script does it in another way, how do they get $(4)$?

Comment: Multiply both sides of equation (3) by $\left<n \right|$.

Comment: Thanks! Then $H^{(0)}$ can act on the $\langle n|$ on its left because it is self-adjoint, so these terms cancel each other and we have $(4)$. (actually I tried that but I didn't use the self-adjointness of $H$).